# replace certain values of multiple vectors

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple 0/1 vectors. For every value = 1, I'd like this value to be replaced by a value of another vector with different content. A testdataset would look like this.

```
name <- c("tim", "tom", "ben", "mary", "jane")
sex <- c("male","male","male","female","female")
jahr <- c(1985, 1986, 1985, 1986, 1984)
v4 <- c(1,0,1,0,1)
v5 <- c(0,0,0,0,1)
v6 <- c(1,0,0,1,1)
v7 <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(name, sex, born, v4,v5,v6,v7)
```

The function I've written looks like this:

```
  df[2,5] <- df[1,"v4"]
  yearset <- function(x) {
                for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {          #jede Spalte
                  for (j in 1:nrow(x)) {        #jede Zeile
                    if (x[j,i] == 1) {          # wenn Wert = 1
                      x[j,i] <- x[j,"jahr"]     # ersetze durch Wert
                      print(paste("column/variable", i, "and row ", j))
                      } 
                  }
                }
  }
```

Problem: nothing happens. I receive no errors, the IF-loops seem to be correct (as shown by the print command) and the functionality of recode-command has been tested just before. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you actually calling the function? When I tried it, I get an error `replacement has length zero`, because you are referencing `x[j,"jahr"]` despite there being no column named `"jahr"`.

Comment: I think you forgot to return something: return(x)

Comment: sorry, @r2evans, "born" == "jahr". I edited. -- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```r
df[4:7] <- lapply(df[4:7], function(x) ifelse(x == 1, df$born, x))

df
#>   name    sex born   v4   v5   v6 v7
#> 1  tim   male 1985 1985    0 1985  0
#> 2  tom   male 1986    0    0    0  0
#> 3  ben   male 1985 1985    0    0  0
#> 4 mary female 1986    0    0 1986  0
#> 5 jane female 1984 1984 1984 1984  0
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to select the correct columns programatically, you can find the subset of columns that match your criteria (here, for example you want all columns that are numeric, except the `born` column, so you can select only those columns that are numeric and have a maximum value of 1):

```r
num_cols <- sapply(df, function(x) if(!is.numeric(x)) FALSE else max(x) < 2)
df[num_cols] <- lapply(df[num_cols], function(x) ifelse(x == 1, df$born, x))

df
#>   name    sex born   v4   v5   v6 v7
#> 1  tim   male 1985 1985    0 1985  0
#> 2  tom   male 1986    0    0    0  0
#> 3  ben   male 1985 1985    0    0  0
#> 4 mary female 1986    0    0 1986  0
#> 5 jane female 1984 1984 1984 1984  0
```

Comment: thanks @allan-cameron, that is pretty smooth though I have to define which columns to look at, where I dont have to do it with my function.

Comment: slinel, what do you mean? *"define which columns to look at"*, your function unnecessarily looks at all columns, inefficient, and a logical error if there happens to be a string `"1"` in one of your non-`v#` columns (unlikely, I admit). I would seriously distrust any solution that unnecessarily looks at the first few columns for no good reason.

Comment: Strongly agree with r2evans - you **should** define which columns to look at. Skipping that step is asking for bugs. There are plenty of ways you could do it - by name, by naming pattern, by index, but you should do it.

Comment: yea, you're right, definitely. what I wished for is having something where I do not have to  look at the columns to know which ones to target. (something like : if numeric, do ..)

Comment: @slinel see my update. You need to define which columns to select, but this can be done programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Another simplification, this one using multiplication:

```
cols = paste0("v", 4:7)
df[cols] = df[cols] * df$born
df
#   name    sex born   v4   v5   v6 v7
# 1  tim   male 1985 1985    0 1985  0
# 2  tom   male 1986    0    0    0  0
# 3  ben   male 1985 1985    0    0  0
# 4 mary female 1986    0    0 1986  0
# 5 jane female 1984 1984 1984 1984  0
```

Comment: pretty smooth, stops working if I dont have dummy values ;)

Comment: Yes, it's very specific to the 1/0 case you present in the question. And that the replacement is numeric. Really, I prefer Allan's answer for both generalizability and clear intent of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below

```
df[-(1:3)] <- df$born * df[-(1:3)]
```

or

```
ids <- startsWith(names(df), "v")
df[ids] <- df$born * df[ids]
```

giving

```
> df
  name    sex born   v4   v5   v6 v7
1  tim   male 1985 1985    0 1985  0
2  tom   male 1986    0    0    0  0
3  ben   male 1985 1985    0    0  0
4 mary female 1986    0    0 1986  0
5 jane female 1984 1984 1984 1984  0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sweep` from `base R`

```
df[-(1:3)] <-  sweep(df[-(1:3)], 1, df$born, `*`)
```